# plistbuddy - How to intercept errors (Key does not exist)

Tags: bash, error-handling

I am reading a plist file, using `plistbuddy`; and I am gathering data from different dictionaries.

The problem is that sometimes the values are not there, for one reason or another, so I get as output `"Key does not exist"`.

Is there a way to intercept this, so that, if the value does not exist, I can substitute it with a 0 or other value?

I use shell script; I was thinking to use a simple `if ... else` statement, tried to check for the string `"key does not exist"`, but it does not work (I never hit the `true` condition, I assume that the message is just going to stdout, instead of being saved in my variable).

The documentation didn't help much, so I got stuck.

Since I calculate the average, an error messes up my calculation, and that's why I want to add a 0, so I can check later on if there are 0 and change the function to calculate the average accordingly.

Basically this is an example of my code: (*filename* is the plist file name)

```
for i in {0..3}
do
    TempValue=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :process:$i:testname:result" $fileName)
    echo $TempValue
    Data_results+=($TempValue)
done 

# Calculate Average
tmpResult=`echo ${Data_results[0]} + ${Data_results[1]} + ${Data_results[2]} + ${Data_results[3]}|bc`
AverageTime=$(bc <<< "scale=10; $tmpResult / 4")  
echo "average for test name: " $AverageValue
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The macOS `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` utility is a well-behaved CLI:

- in case of success, its exit code is `0`
- in case of failure, its exit code is nonzero
- its regular output is sent to `stdout`, error messages are sent to `stderr`

There are various ways of checking for success; e.g.:

```sh
# Query and save the value; suppress any error message, if key not found.
val=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print ":SomeKey"' file 2>/dev/null)

# Save the exit code, which indicates success v. failure
exitCode=$? 

if (( exitCode == 0 )) then # OK
   # handle success ....
else
   # handle failure ...
fi
```

---

**Update 1**

Here's a snippet for your particular use case; you can run it as-is to see how it works (it uses the Plist file in which `Finder` stores its preferences):

```sh
# Loop over keys and retrieve the corresponding values.
# If the key doesn't exist, assign '0'.
for key in ':AppleShowAllFiles' ':NoSuchKey'; do
    val=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print \"$key\"" \
          ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist 2>/dev/null || printf '0')
    echo "Value retrieved: [$val]"
done
```

As you'll see, `$val` will contain `0` in the case of the 2nd, non-existent key.

The  `2>/dev/null` redirection suppresses stderr output (error messages) and  the `||` operator is used to provide an alternative command to create output in case the invocation of `PlistBuddy` indicates failure (via its exit code).

The only caveat is that you won't be able to distinguish a non-existent key from a more fundamental failure, such as a non-existent or corrupted Plist file. Handling that would be more involved, because `PlistBuddy` doesn't use distinct exit codes to distinguish these cases.

---

**Update 2**

Here's a streamlined version of your code that includes the desired default-to-0 logic:

```
# Collect temperatures.
Data_results=()
for i in {0..3}
do
    Data_results+=( $(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
            -c "print :process:$i:testname:result" "$fileName" 2>/dev/null || 
            printf '0') )
done 

# Calculate average
AverageValue=$(bc <<< \
                "scale=10; $(( ${Data_results[@]/%/ +} 0 )) / ${#Data_results[@]}")  
echo "average for test name: " $AverageValue
```

Note: `$(( ... ))` is an arithmetic expansion (integers only) that uses a little trick to sum up the elements of the array: `${Data_results[@]/%/ +}` appends  `+` to each element of the array. E.g., an input array of `(1 2 3)` would expand to `1 + 2 + 3 +`; since that leaves a dangling `+`, I simply added another `0` to form a valid expression.
Combined with dividing by `${#Data_results[@]}` - the number of elements in the array - the command then works with an array of any size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware that it returns an error code when failing, but it won't behave as I expect it would. I have an if where I loop trough a plist, I collect 4 values; if one of the values is not there, I don't simply exit...the script continue. So I can't use the exit code, due the fact that I don't execute the utility just once, but it is part of a more complex shell script.

Comment: @newbiez: I think you have a misconception about exit codes: every invocation of a command inside a script sets an exit code, indicating how that very command exited in terms of success vs. failure. You can access this exit code explicitly with `$?`, or you can use `if` statements and the `&&` and `||` operators to act on either success or failure. Please see my updated answer for a snippet that hopefully does what you want.

Comment: Indeed I was not aware of that; I simply thought that the exit code is either called by you somewhere in the script, with "exit", or when the script reach the end. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: +1 Excellent, thanx especially for 2>/dev/null || printf default_value